# Javascript that renders header not working in IE11 only on some computers

Tags: javascript, html, css, security, internet-explorer

I have a site that has a header that is rendered through javascript. My clients report that the header navbar is missing in IE; they've tested this on several computers. However, my coworkers and I have not been able to reproduce the issue. We had issues before with the security settings in IE 11 blocking scripts, so I tried increasing my security settings, and I also tried putting IE in compatibility mode as well as viewing the page in IE 8. Nothing I've done has caused the navbar to disappear.

This is the screenshot that I got from my clients

[image]

This is what it looks like on my computer, on all browsers

[image]

I think this file is important, because when I deleted it in the debugger, I was able to reproduce the missing header issue. However I'm not sure if this is the only thing that's being blocked, and I'm not sure why it would be blocked.

```
thisdir="/sites/all/themes/munson/js";
stm_bm(["menu0ca1",900,"",thisdir+"/blank.gif",0,"","",0,0,250,0,50,1,0,0,"","100%",0,0,1,2,"default","hand","",1,25],this);
stm_bp("p0",[0,4,0,0,0,0,130,0,100,"",-2,"",-2,50,0,0,"#999999","transparent","",0,0,0,"#000000"]);
stm_ai("p0i0",[0,"","","",-1,-1,0,"http://munsonhealthcare.org","_self","","Munson Healthcare System",thisdir+"/MHCClear.png",thisdir+"/MHCClear.png",130,44,0,"","",0,0,0,1,1,"#0099cc",1,"",0,"",thisdir+"/navHoverBkg2.gif",3,3,0,0,"#FFFFF7","#000000","#ffffff","#ffffff","10.88px Verdana","10.88px Verdana",0,0,"","","","",0,0,0],114,0);
stm_aix("p0i1","p0i0",[2,"",thisdir+"/divider.png",thisdir+"/divider.png",12,44,0,"","_self","","","","",0,0,0,"","",0,0,0,1,1,"#0099cc",1,"#FFFFFF",1,"","",3,3,0,0,"#FFFFF7","#000000","#ffffff","#ffffff","10pt Verdana","10pt Verdana"],12,0);
stm_aix("p0i2","p0i0",[0,"","","",-1,-1,0,"http://www.munsonhealthcare.org/munsonhealthcarefacilities","_self","","Our Locations",thisdir+"/LocationClear.png",thisdir+"/LocationClear.png",130,44,0,"","",-1,-1,0,1,1,"#0099cc",1,"",0,"",thisdir+"/navHoverBkg2.gif",3,3,0,0,"#cccccc","#68a4ca"],130,0);
stm_bp("p1",[1,4,0,2,2,3,0,0,100,"stEffect(\"slip\")",-2,"stEffect(\"slip\")",-2,80,0,0,"#999999","#e8eff6","",3,1,1,"#cccccc"]);
stm_aix("p1i0","p0i0",[0,"    Charlevoix Area Hospital","","",-1,-1,0,"http://www.cah.org","_blank","","Charlevoix Area Hospital","","",0,0,0,"","",0,0,0,0,1,"#e8eff6",0,"#68a4ca",0,"","",1,0,0,0,"#cccccc","#68a4ca","#027abd","#e8eff6","12px 'Arial','Verdana'","12px 'Arial','Verdana'"],0,25);
stm_aix("p1i1","p1i0",[0,"    Kalkaska Memorial Health Center","","",-1,-1,0,"http://munsonhealthcare.org/KMHC","_self",""," Kalkaska Memorial Health Center"],0,25);
stm_aix("p1i2","p1i0",[0,"    Mercy Hospital Cadillac","","",-1,-1,0,"http://www.mercyhealthcadillac.com/welcome-cadillac","_blank","","Mercy Hospital Cadillac","","",0,0,0,"","",0,0,0,0,1,"#e8eff6",0,"#68a4ca",0,"","",1,0,0,0,"#cccccc","#68a4ca","#2089c4"],0,25);
stm_aix("p1i3","p1i2",[0,"    Mercy Hospital Grayling","","",-1,-1,0,"http://www.mercyhealthgrayling.com/welcome-grayling","_blank","","Mercy Hospital Grayling"],0,25);
stm_aix("p1i4","p1i2",[0,"    Munson Medical Center","","",-1,-1,0,"http://www.munsonhealthcare.org/MMC","_self","","  Munson Medical Center"],0,25);
stm_aix("p1i5","p1i2",[0,"    Munson Home Health","","",-1,-1,0,"http://www.munsonhomehealth.org/","_self","","Munson Home Health"],0,25);
stm_aix("p1i6","p1i2",[0,"    Northwest Michigan Surgery Center    ","","",-1,-1,0,"http://northwestmichigansurgerycenter.com","_blank","","Northwest Michigan Surgery Center  "],0,25);
stm_aix("p1i7","p1i2",[0,"    Otsego Memorial Hospital","","",-1,-1,0,"http://www.myomh.org/","_blank",""," Otsego Memorial Hospital"],0,25);
stm_aix("p1i8","p1i2",[0,"    Paul Oliver Memorial Hospital","","",-1,-1,0,"http://www.munsonhealthcare.org/POMH","_self",""," Paul Oliver Memorial Hospital"],0,25);
stm_aix("p1i9","p1i2",[0,"    West Shore Medical Center  ","","",-1,-1,0,"http://www.westshoremedcenter.org/","_blank","","West Shore Medical Hospital  "],0,25);
stm_ep();
stm_aix("p0i3","p0i1",[2,"",thisdir+"/divider.png",thisdir+"/divider.png",12,44,0,"","_self","","","","",0,0,0,"","",0,0,0,1,1,"#0099cc",1,"#0099cc"],12,0);
stm_aix("p0i4","p0i0",[0,"","","",-1,-1,0,"http://www.munsonhealthcare.org/forphysicians","_self","","For Physicians",thisdir+"/PHYClear.png",thisdir+"/PHYClear.png",130,44,0,"","",0,0,0,1,1,"#0099cc",1,"#0099cc"],114,0);
stm_aix("p0i5","p0i3",[],12,0);
stm_aix("p0i6","p0i4",[0,"","","",-1,-1,0,"http://www.munsonhealthcare.org/?id=1233&sid=8","_self","","For Employees",thisdir+"/EMPClear.png",thisdir+"/EMPClear.png"],114,0);
stm_aix("p0i7","p0i3",[],12,0);
stm_aix("p0i8","p0i4",[0,"","","",-1,-1,0,"http://www.munsonhealthcare.org/?id=479&sid=1","_self","","Contact Us",thisdir+"/ContactClear.png",thisdir+"/ContactClear.png"],114,0);
stm_aix("p0i9","p0i3",[],12,0);
stm_aix("p0i10","p0i0",[0,"","","",-1,-1,0,"","_self","","","","",130,44,0,"","",0,0,0,1,1,"#0099cc",1,"#0099cc",1,"",""],114,0);
stm_aix("p0i11","p0i10",[0,"","","",-1,-1,0,"","_self","","","","",0,0],114,0);
stm_aix("p0i12","p0i11",[],105,0);
stm_ep();
stm_em();
```

What I can't figure out is why would this script be not working in IE 11 only on some computers? If it's not an issue with security settings or compatibility mode, what's the problem?

Note: I'm not sure if this is important, but there was no problem in IE before I changed the navbar background. The navbar uses a png for its background, and I changed which file it was using. However, when I tried changing it back to the original png file, that did not fix the issue on my client's computer.

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: No, nothing. I also viewed the html and the header HTML simply isn't there.

Comment: Do they have any extension that could be blocking the script (e.g. adblock or similars)?

Comment: I'll check, one thing I noticed is that when I delete that script, it prevents three other scripts from loading, and the three scripts that are loaded are from another domain. Maybe that's what the problem is?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure they don't JavaScript turned off in the browser settings?